# Optimize subquery for better performance?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Consider this table, `table1`

```
User_ID     Field           Value
1           balance         232
1           last_active     1525690435
2           balance         345
2           last_active     1525690430
```

To get the sum of balance of users, given their last_active is > X, I can use subquery such as

```
SELECT SUM(Value) FROM table1 WHERE Field = 'balance' AND User_ID IN (
    SELECT User_ID FROM table1 WHERE Field = 'last_active' AND Value > X
)
```

Are there any better way to get the same result?

Comment: @Ryan . . . Your sample query has nothing to do with your sample data.

Comment: I believe you forget the `and field='balance'` in the question

Comment: ID vs. User_ID?

Comment: Are you storing a timestamp and a (I guess monetary) value in the same column? And `field` determines the semantic? If so, I strongly recommend to divide that into two separate columns or tables if it's independant of each other.

Comment: @jarlh... I think it is `TYPO`.

Comment: @YogeshSharma, as you already have noticed it makes a difference - is a sub-query needed or not.

Comment: Sorry all, I have fixed the SQL above.

Answer (score 2):

1. Do not design a table like that, use 3rd normalization when you know the data structure.
2. Create an index

Answer (score 1):

You can write the query so it is syntactically and logically correct (based on your sample data):

```
SELECT SUM(Value)
FROM table1
WHERE field = 'balance' AND
      User_ID IN (SELECT USER_ID
                  FROM table1
                  WHERE field = 'last_active' AND value > X 
                 );
```

For performance, I would recommend `EXISTS` and an index on `table1(USER_ID, field, value)`:

```
SELECT SUM(t1.Value)
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.field = 'balance' AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM table1 tt1
              WHERE tt1.USER_ID = t1.USER_ID AND
                    tt1.field = 'last_active' AND tt1.value > X 
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `exists` instead

```
SELECT SUM(Value) Value
FROM table1 t
WHERE Field = 'balance' AND          
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM table1 
              WHERE User_ID = t.User_ID AND
                    Field = ' last_active' AND value > X);
```

Answer (score 0):

**TRY:** If you are working in the single table

```
SELECT SUM(Value) FROM table1 WHERE field = 'balance' AND last_active > X
```

By seeing `User_ID` and `ID` in the query it seems you are using two separate tables so you can write the query as

```
SELECT SUM(A.Value)
FROM table1 A
INNER JOIN table2 B ON B.id = A.User_Id
    AND B.last_active > 'x'
WHERE A.field = 'field = 'balance'
```